# Can symbolic links be used for website URLs?

Tags: linux, webserver, symbolic-link, url, drupal

I'm developing a new website to replace our old website. The URL the dev site is 11.22.33.44/~abc/ (not that IP exactly) because that's what Host Gator gave me to use. Once complete, I'll change DNS servers so our domian name points to that server and not our old one.

I'm using Drupal and am taking great care to keep all links relative. However, because of the /~abc/ in the dev URL, it's not always possible to keep it relative and many links will break. Within the drupal system or anywhere drupal PHP is used, like for menus, it can figure out the URL on it's own. But for any images and links entered into the WYSIWYG, those will break.

Can a soft link (symbolic link) fix this problem? Should I use the command `ln -s /~abc /`? Will the URL `mywebsite.org/~abc/node/1` then show the page `mywebsite.org/node/1` ??

I know this is not ideal for SEO, maintenance, and other reasons. But it would make the migration much smoother and quicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sym link will take care of your file system problem. Make sure you have the same permissions for folders and files in both your old app and your new one.

For your images, I would take a look at 301/302 redirects. Take a look at this post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700621/htaccess-r-301-vs-r-302

Hope that helps!

Comment: I choose this as the best answer because it will solve my problem and will work. However, there *may* be a better way to do it but it would require using this from the start. It involves modifying the hosts file on my workstation to go to the IP address when I use our domain name in my bowser. Here's the link to the Q/A on webmasters.stackexchange.com: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68714/can-a-soft-link-be-used-to-fix-url-problems/68715?noredirect=1#comment77323_68715